# Error uploading spatial data to existing RPostgreSql table using sf::st_write() in R

Tags: r, postgresql, postgis, r-sf

I created the following RPostgreSql table with a primary key and foreign key:

```
create table
us_hurricanes (
    id         serial                        primary key
  , geo_id     int                           references geo_id_master_list(geo_id)
  , storm_id   text                          not null
  , timestamp  timestamp with time zone      not null
  , radii      int                           not null
  , geom       geometry(multipolygon, 2163)  not null
);
```

It currently contains some observations. In **R**, I am trying to use the `sf::st_write()` function to upload additional entries to the table:

```
db <- RPostgreSQL::dbConnect(
    dbDriver("PostgreSQL"),
    dbname = NAME,
    host = HOST,
    port = PORT,
    user = USER,
    password = PASS)

sf::st_write(
    new_data, 
    dsn = db, 
    layer = "us_hurricanes",
    append = TRUE)
```

where `new_data` is a dataframe that contains all of the same fields that are in the `us_hurricanes` table, and the `geom` column is an `sfc_POLYGON` object with CRS of 2163.

```
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 5 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 2628189 ymin: -2026100 xmax: 3092784 ymax: -1531227
Projected CRS: US National Atlas Equal Area
    id geo_id storm_id           timestamp radii                           geom
1 3210   3210 al072022 2022-09-21 12:00:00    34 POLYGON ((2783123 -1544385,...
```

I get the following non-descriptive error when I run  the `st_write()` function above:

```
Error in nchar(sm[1L], type = "w") : invalid multibyte string, element 1
```

A few observations:

- If I use a new table name as the `layer` value in the `st_write()` function, no error occurs. Instead, it creates a new table in my DB, but the `SRID` of the table is 0.
- If I don't use the `append = TRUE` argument, the table is successfully overwritten.
- If I write the dataframe to a shapefile, use `shp2pgsql` to create a `.sql` file, and run that file via the command line, the new entries are successfully uploaded to the existing table.

How can I navigate this issue? Is there a better alternative in R to upload new spatial entries to an existing Postgres table?

Comment: It would help if your question lists all  loaded packages at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the database connection with the newer `RPostgres` package rather than `RPostgreSQL`?

From `help(st_write)`:
"we officially test support for RPostgres::Postgres() connections".